# Arraging multiple 3D plots

Tags: r-plotly

I have created 6 3D plots that I need to include in a research paper. However, I need to all the plots in a grid.

I've been trying the function subplot but all my plots are combining instead of forming a grid. I have tried setting nrows to various numbers but it does not change the layout. Any ideas on how to fix this? Or other functions that may serve the same purpose?

Shows the function for 1/6 plots, then the subplot function. to the right is the output:

[image: Shows the function for 1/6 plots, then the subplot function. to the right is is the output]

Comment: You could try adding the parameters `shareY = F, shareX = F` to the `subplot` function. Another option would be to use `cowplot::plotgrid`. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput(head(dataObject))`, the code (never a picture of your code!), and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). So if neither of these works for you, then edit your question and make it reproducible.

Comment: Consider adding the code as text block with appropriate format instead of screen shots